# How do i remove the black colour behind the image in GLSurfaceview?

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnTV4.jpg

Is there any way I can get rid of the black colour in the Image (please check the link ) . I tried adding it in a Framelayout with a view underneath it but couldnt get it to work . Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks !

**Update**

Below is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="PhotoEd"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/graphics_frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <com.example.nawabhussain.photoed.utils.MyGlSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is how i set it in my Activity.

```
 MyGlSurfaceView view = (MyGlSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);
    view.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    view.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    view.setRenderer(new TextureRenderer(this));
    view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

Is there any way I could set the black area to some colour ?

Comment: If you're using GLSurfaceView in its default configuration, there is nothing behind it. The Surface is on a separate layer behind the View UI, so you can't put anything behind it. You can change its Z-ordering relative to the View layer (with e.g. `setZOrderOnTop()`), though it's not clear that you actually want that. What does "get rid of" mean? You want it to look the same but in a different color? You want to expand the image? You can put stuff *on top of* a GLSurfaceView, so if you want to cover up the areas with something else it's straightforward to do so.

Comment: @fadden i updated the answer , can you take a look at it ?

Comment: @taawanzad did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in your XML layout. This will stretch the image to fill the whole `ImageView`.